# Change NULL value to TOTAL from ROLL UP FUNCTION

Tags: mysql, sql, null, rollup

Good day 
I try to change value of NULL from roll up function to null but I receive an error of

> GROUPING FUNCTION DOES NOT EXIST

. Please check my code below.

```
 SELECT
    CASE
WHEN GROUPING (`ProductName`) = 1 THEN
    'TOTAL'
ELSE
    CAST(`ProductName` AS VARCHAR(10))
END `ProductName`,
 SUM(`Quantity`),
 SUM(`Price Paid`)
FROM
    `bacoor_products`
GROUP BY
    `ProductName` WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Not Grouping function but may be group_concat function use

Comment: what did you intend to do with the **Grouping** function. By the way, there's no such function in MySQL.

Comment: Use COALESCE(ProductName, 'Total'). `Grouping` exists in MS SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no grouping function in mysql but you can try as per below-

```
SELECT IFNULL(`ProductName`, 'Total') AS 'ProductName', SUM(`Quantity`), 
SUM(`Price Paid`) FROM `bacoor_products` GROUP BY `ProductName` WITH ROLLUP
```